# regarding "how you paid and how you get the ticket?"

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following conversation grammatically?

> **Me**: Have you bought the air ticket via this agency directly?
>   **Jack**: I bought once.
>   **me**: How you paid and how you get the ticket?

Comment: This is Not A Real Question. It's just proofreading, and despite having already received **three** upvotes, the only answer so far still contains errors (most glaringly, ***the** air ticket* is clearly incorrect in this context).

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use the adjective *grammatical* rather than *grammatically* in the question.
Second, the conversation is more appropriate as below.

> **Me**: Have you ever bought the air ticket via this agency directly?
>   **Jack**: Yes, I did once.
>   **Me**: How did you pay and get the ticket?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would refer to my lines as *Myself*, not Me (esp. in written form)

> Myself: Have you bought the **airline** ticket via this agency directly?

The ticket is for the airline, not the air. While *bought* is OK, *purchased* might be better. *Bought* is better suited for physical goods like groceries.

> Jack: Yes, I did.

You do not need to repeat what is already known from the previous conversation.

> Myself: How **did** you **pay** and (how did you) get the ticket?

*did* is needed since you are asking a question. The second *how did you* is not required but since *pay* and *get* are different actions, it may be clearer to include it.

Also, *pay* and *get* are present tense forms. *did* marks the past occurrance, as the question refers to events in the past. For example:

In the present:

> How **do** you **pay** your electric bill?

In the past:

> How **did** you **pay** your electric bill?

Comment: Thanks, but why using "Yes, I did." instead of "Yes, I have."?

Comment: @william007 "did" is an action done in the past and already completed. "have" by itself indicates possession (I have the book.). "have" can also be a helper verb but in this case also requires a main verb (I had gone to buy a ticket.)